# How to remove parentheses around records when saveAsTextFile on RDD[(String, Int)]?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm using `saveAsTextFile(path)` in order to save output as text file in later to import the result to DB. The output looks something like this:

```
(value1, value2)
```

How to remove the parentheses?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can try the following which is very basic:

```
rdd.map(x => x._1 + "," + x._2).saveAsTextFile(path)
```

You just map your RDD[(A,B)] to an RDD[String] and save it.

Comment: @Ashish if you have a comment, please use the comment box and don't edit the answer ! Also The code you suggested in the edit isn't related to the question here. Your code is working with a RDD[Row] which is not the case here.

Answer (score 7):

Before making `saveAsTextFile` use `map(x => x.mkString(",")`

`rdd.map(x => x.mkString(",").saveAsTextFile(path)`

Output will not have bracket.

Answer (score 3):

For the folks in the Java world, here is a solution that starts with a DataFrame, converts it to an RDD and then writes the results.  The rows of the RDD are passed through the map function that converts the Row into a String.

```
public void write(DataFrame output) {
    String path = "your_path_goes_here";
    output
        .toJavaRDD()
        .map(new BracketRemover())
        .saveAsTextFile(path);
}

protected class BracketRemover implements Function<Row, String> {
    public String call(Row r) {
        return r.mkString(",");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try explicitly using `mkString` rather than just printing a tuple directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can save rdd by using
rdd.map(rec => rec.productIterator.mkString(","). saveAsTextFile(path)
Resulting dataset will not have parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is tagged Scala, but just to add on Python's side in case anyone is curious. Create the RDD and save as is

```
rdd_of_tuples = sc.parallelize([('one',1),('two',2)])
rdd_of_tuples.saveAsTextFile('/user/cloudera/rdd_of_tuples')
```

This will save the rows like this as you mention

```
('one', 1)
```

But if you do the following it should work

```
rdd_of_text = rdd_of_tuples.map(lambda (x,y): x + ',' + str(y)).saveAsTextFile('/user/cloudera/rdd_of_text')
```

And you should get

```
one,1
```

Note that in this particular case you need to be aware of the types for concatenating (check the str(y)), else you would get the following exception

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```