# Spark saveAsTextFile() writes to multiple files instead of one

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am using Spark and Scala on my laptop at this moment.

When I write an RDD to a file, the output is written to two files "part-00000" and "part-00001". How can I force Spark / Scala to **write to one file**?

My code is currently:

```
myRDD.map(x => x._1 + "," + x._2).saveAsTextFile("/path/to/output")
```

where I am [removing the parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29945330/remove-parentheses-from-output-in-spark) to write out key,value pairs.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The "problem" is indeed a feature, and it is produced by how your `RDD` is partitioned, hence it is separated in `n` parts where `n` is the number of partitions. To fix this you just need to change the number of partitions to one, by using [repartition](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=repartition#pyspark.RDD.repartition) on your `RDD`. The documentation states:

> repartition(numPartitions)
>
> Return a new RDD that has exactly numPartitions partitions.
>
> Can increase or decrease the level of parallelism in this RDD. Internally, this uses a shuffle to redistribute data. If you are
>   decreasing the number of partitions in this RDD, consider using
>   coalesce, which can avoid performing a shuffle.

For example, this change should work.

```
myRDD.map(x => x._1 + "," + x._2).repartition(1).saveAsTextFile("/path/to/output")
```

As the documentation says you can also use [coalesce](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=coalesce#pyspark.RDD.coalesce), which is actually the recommended option when you are reducing the number of partitions. However, reducing the number of partitions to one is considered a bad idea, because it causes shuffling of the data to one node and loss of parallelism.

Comment: Please stress that it is a really bad idea in general :)

Comment: @zero323 Even more, the documentation says that it is recommended to use `coalesce`

Comment: Coalesce won't help. In case of "wide" transformations it will do the same amount of work.

Comment: @zero323 Just to confirm, the problem comes because of shuffling and because of the lose of parallelism, and moving all data to one node, right? That's what I missed right?

Comment: I think that's it. There should be no more issues here.

Comment: Oh, there is also checksum computation. And if this is is a on DFS a single node has to replicate all data.